# ¿Cómo crear una imagen de Appstream y modificarla usando solo comandos de AWS CLI?

Tags: imagen, aws, cli

Quiero automatizar un proceso en AWS donde se genera una imagen de Appstream a partir de una anterior. El proceso es el siguiente:

1. Se inicia un image builder que usa una imagen anterior
2. Se conecta al image builder y se carga un zip dentro del image builder
3. La carpeta "dev" que se usa en el directorio "C:\app" se elimina
4. Del zip que se cargó se saca la nueva carpeta "dev" y se copia en el directorio "C:\app"
5. Se borra el zip
6. Se crea la nueva imagen dandole un nuevo nombre y tags necesarios

El problema que tengo es que no he encontrado una forma de crear la imagen de Appstream con solo comandos de CLI. Pareciera que para manipular archivos dentro de la imagen debo usar necesariamente la interfaz gráfica del Image Builder.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer lo que busco?